# SQL Server connects by IP but not by name

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was given with a new server. I created the database and required logins. 
From server everything is fine, I can connect to server through server name or IP with the new logins.

However when I tried to connect from my client machine SSMS though servername it is not showing error

[image]

But instead of server name if I use **server IP** it is connecting. Really I am exhausted with this issue

Comment: Perhaps a firewall is blocking the default sql server port (1433)?

Comment: @ZoharPeled  but if I use server `IP` in server name from Client machine it is connecting.

Comment: The error message tells you that the network path was not found. So your client machine cannot resolve your server name to an IP. How is the network / setup?

Comment: Also we have already created a Rule in server firewall for port 1433. It is open

Comment: Oh, Sorry, I misunderstood the question. Look into what @Allan said.

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen -   Sorry am not good in DBA stuff. Can you please tell me what information you want by saying *How is the network / setup?.*

Comment: It's not really DBA stuff but network / server architecture and host names etc.
Personally, I'd really consider just using the IP address because it's a common way to access remote servers. Is there a requirement that it has to be a name?

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen - It is not a requirement. But we have connected our old server with name only. So just curious what is wrong with new server

Answer (score 0):

Can you check your host file available at C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts?
You need to make entry of IP Address and HostName in hosts file as given below.

```
# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost
    192.162.56.101  ServerName
```